# 417 - This device has an empty configuration for the edge agent?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have created an Azure IoT Edge device by following the steps outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux

When I create a deployment and check the IoT Edge device I see the following error message:

```
417 - This device has an empty configuration for the edge agent. Please set a deployment manifest.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens when you create an Edge device in Azure IoT Hub and then launch the Edge runtime *before* setting up modules for the device in IoT Hub. Once a deployment has been done and the Edge runtime sees it, this should go away.